# moving, rotating or scaling doesn't affect the mesh, it only affects its borders

Tags: mesh, error, geometry

I bought a PC for my friend, and installed blender 2.8 and 2.9 but in both I have the same problem, when I G, R, S it doesn't move the mesh it only affects its borders, its completely weird, please look at the screenshot you will understand.
[image]
It works at my PC very well but doesn't work on his, what do you guys think.
I want to teach him blender but it won't work on his PC.

Comment: This issue is commonly caused by a non-supported GPU or out of date graphics drivers. Check here to make sure your card is supported (Must support OpenGL 3.3) - https://code.blender.org/2019/04/supported-gpus-in-blender-2-80/ Update your drivers if needed.

Comment: his graphic details are in this pic https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e3Q7bMwf9niPI_W-A6Dt_O1q0nvYQhmG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ChristopherBennett also when I go to render mode this error shows up: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mwQezhxdA3NrJ95aiBusXjji4jAmqMNy/view?usp=sharing